# Is there a way to use Linq to display an item with the highest result without duplication of a specific name?

Tags: c#, linq, data-manipulation

I am trying to add a feature to my website where the teacher can see a summary of students who have completed goals that week.
This is my controller method

```
public IActionResult WeeklyDetails()
        {
            var user = svc.GetUser(GetSignedInUserId());
           
            var goals = svc.GetGoalsForTeacher(user.Id);
            

            var mostRecentMonday = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);//get week start of most recent Monday morning
            var weekEnd = mostRecentMonday.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1); //will return the end of the day on Sunday


            var results = goals.Where(g => g.AchievedOn >= mostRecentMonday && g.AchievedOn <= weekEnd).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
            {
                //Get count of current element to before:
                int count = results.Take(i + 1)
                                .Count(r => r.Student.Name == results[i].Student.Name);
                results[i].Count = count;
            }


       
            var result = results.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                                .Select(group => group.First()).ToList();     
           
            return View(result);


        }
```

In my cshtml view page I call the details like this

```
 @foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item.Student.Name @item.Count</p>
}
```

However, I achieve this result

```
Emma 1

Emma 2

Sarah 1
```

This is because emma has two goals which are completed in the list I know, however I would prefer for Emma 2 to be the only result that is shown. Is there a way to choose Max and then the first? Maybe not, my apologies if this is unclear.

Comment: You're real close to a great question. Most of your question is about linq and data manipulation rather than ASP.Net, so we can trim out everything doing with MVC and razor out and just focus on the data to make a great [mre]. Your problem seems to be between defining `results` and defining `result`, so everything else can be removed. For example, what's the value of `goals`? Giving us that MRE will help us and yourself greatly.

Comment: Hello, the value of goals are all the goals the teacher has set for every student, including a title, feedback, studentId, count, creationDate, achievedDate and boolean for isAchieved. All I want to pull from it are the completed goals that week and tally them up students who have completed. I am a beginner, again apologies if this is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the definition of result, but I think you group by the primary key of result (x.Id). You use the original result list as model of your view. But you provide aggregated data, so I would create a clean type (can be done inside your controller class as nested class):

```cs
public class GoalSummary
{
    public int StudentId {get;set;}
    public string Firstname {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Goals {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can use grouping and projecting (select) to create this results:

```cs
var summary = goals
    .Where(g => g.AchievedOn >= mostRecentMonday && g.AchievedOn <= weekEnd)
    .GroupBy(g => new {g.Student.Id, g.Student.Firstname, g.Student.Name})
    .Select(g => new GoalSummary
    {
        StudentId =  g.Key.Id,
        Firstname = g.Key.Firstname,
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        Goals = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
return View(summary);
```

If you are familiar with SQL: We want StudentId, Firstname, Name and COUNT(*). So we have to group by Id, Firstname and Name.

In your View you can use your typed summary:

```cs
@model List<YourNamespace.Controllers.YourController.GoalSummary>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! Is it OK practice to have the extra GoalSummary? This has helped so much I really appreciate it.

Comment: This classes are called DTO (data transfer object) classes. They have no logic and contains only properties (or fields with constructors) for your data. It is a common pattern. You need them if you want to pass your result as a parameter to another method. In this case the View() method.